# wp_insert_post alternatives for faster process

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm using `wp_insert_post` to generate posts for my site. Initially, everything works fine and it was very fast. When the number of posts accummulated to about 3000, it became very slow and now i almost cannot insert post anymore using that command. I tested the same script on another newly created database on the same server, everything runs very fast.

I have deactivated all plugins and turn off pinging service, but there is no improvement.

i used `$id = wp_insert_post($array)` to retrieve the post_id also. Anyone know how to resolve my problem? Is any other method to generate posts and get the post_id

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show the complete code you're using?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be getting this problem, I have a site with more 10000 posts using this function all the time and everything works fine. Try running a [cleanup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cleanup/) in your database to see if things get better.